# ios webview editor layout on Ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, ipad, native

In my ios application I open webview. My html page contains set of html5 input controls (text, date, time, select etc). When users click on that controls browser shows their native editors.

When I open that page on [iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVZFi.png) I have nice looking editor in the down of a page, but in case of [ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT1Kb.png) all that editors (except text) appears as popups over editable controls. And that ipad popover controls does not have previous/next buttons, which are really useful in my case.

Can I pin on ipad that editors to the bottom like in iphone. 
If it's not possible, can I add at least previous/next buttons to that editors.

I understand that these editors will look big on ipad because of screen size, but in my case it's even better because my goal is to provide easy way to enter data.

Thanks for help